# Camera animation with position.set on Three.js

Tags: three.js, camera, onclick, rotation

I have a little problem with my camera..
The camera change position when click the marker and its ok, but i need to make a animation when my camera change position.

Part of code when click marker:

```
var radius1 = 1.030;

var city = {
    "name": "city1",
    "lat": 43+2,
    "lng": 11-15
};

var label = new InfoBox(city, radius1, document.body);

var map66 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "images/marker.png" );
var material66 = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map66, color: 0xffffff } 
);

var marker1 = new THREE.Sprite( material66 );
marker1.scale.set(0.1,0.1,1);
marker1.position.copy(label.position);
scene.add(marker1);

var markerarry = [];
markerarry.push(marker1);

 window.onmousedown = function(event) {

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(markerarry, false);
    for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {

        controls.autoRotate = false;
        controls.enableRotate = false;
        controls.enableZoom = false;
        var zInMin = 15;
        for (camera.fov; camera.fov > zInMin; camera.fov -= 0.01) {

            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            //camera position set
            camera.position.set(3.5, 3.5, 0.4);

            //need make animation!!


        }

    }

renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

now it's like that:

[now](https://i.gyazo.com/f831792e3bcbb76e317ff0d96867e1ce.mp4)

how I want it to be:

[want](https://i.gyazo.com/a104f3c682718974f6a21ebb78a47eaf.mp4)

Is anyone there to help me without upsetting my example too much?

Answer (score 0):

Add Tween.js

after change render function and add animate function like:

```
function animate() {
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    TWEEN.update();
    render();
}

function render() {
    controls.update();
    //requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

next

```
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(markerarry, false);
    for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {

        /////////////////////////////////////
        //it help to find coordinate after set camera and click on marker
        //console.log(camera.position);
        ////////////////////////////////////

        controls.enabled = false;
        var duration = 2500;
        var position = new THREE.Vector3().copy(camera.position);
        var targetPosition = new THREE.Vector3(2.4, 2.2, -0.6);

        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(position)
            .to(targetPosition, duration)
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Back.InOut )
            .onUpdate(function () {
                camera.position.copy(position);
                camera.lookAt( controls.target );
            })
            .onComplete(function () {
                camera.position.copy( targetPosition );
                camera.lookAt( controls.target );
                controls.enabled = true;
            })
            .start();
    }
```

The animation now:

[Yep!](https://i.gyazo.com/64908b07967bb9880c714911f2f66ad0.mp4)